# Perl 5.6.1 Installation

Tags: perl, path, installation, export

I have perl 5.8.8 in usr/bin, I need to install perl 5.6.1 in my redhat into this directory appl/virtuo/gways without uninstalling the 5.8.8. I need for the perl 5.6.1 to be my default perl. I am not sure how to install it and export the path....

Comment: Installation instructions in INSTALL file. The "default" Perl is whichever one appears first in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) for running multiple instances of perl